# Mono-Droid and app delivery

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a C# app that manages a few aspects of my Dungeons & Dragons like game. One of my friend is the DM and needs specific tools to help him manage the world information better. So i proposed to do it but the tools i need to do require a good deal of crunching power so i don't want to do them using PHP/MySQL. (The other reason is that C# will be much easier to achieve that world generator too)

It's not clear on the Xanarin website and on mono-droid.com wiki if you can deploy an application manually and install it manually on your phone or on a friend's tablet pc without having to pay the HUGE 400$ fee.

I'm just trying to build a C# app for myself and my friends, nothing commercial that i'll sell back, so i find the 400$ a bit too costly for me, but the free version allows you to only emulate your app and if you want to deploy, you'll have to pay for the licence fee... hugh...

So is there a way to do this without ripping off my pockets...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no. As you mentioned, the evaluation version of Mono for Android only allows deployment to the emulator. Deployment to devices currently requires a full license.

Depending on your needs, if the license fee is too high for your project, I'd recommend taking a look at the standard Java tools for developing Android applications, which are free of charge. If you're looking to leverage existing .NET code in the application or are already very familiar with C#, the license may potentially be worthwhile just for the time it could save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worthwhile for the save of trouble cause i don't know anything about Java, but not worthwhile for the cash flow i have to spend from my pockets... want to give me that 400$? :P

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is a way to get it deployed to the phone without that fee.

Comment: Apart from Java and C#/mono-droid, do you know any other way i could build an app that can be installed on my friends tablet and not require internet?